# How to store/show timestamp and double columns with 15 decimal precision?

Tags: cassandra, timestamp, time-series, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

I would like to insert experimental data into Cassandra where each data has     precision of 15 decimal places. The sample dataset is as follows:

```
+------------------+-------------------+
|   Sampling_Rate  |       Value1      |
+------------------+-------------------+
| 2.48979187011719 | 0.144110783934593 |
+------------------+-------------------+
```

I would like to see the **Sampling_Rate** as an Epoch time (i.e. *1970-01-01 00:00:02.48979187011719+0000*), and **Value1** to store its full precision value.

For this, I inserted data with the describe table :

```sql
CREATE TABLE project_fvag.temp (
    sampling_rate timestamp PRIMARY KEY,
    value1 double ) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

I also changed the cqlshrc file with increasing precision for both float and double. Also, changed the datetimeformat:

```
datetimeformat = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%.15f%z ;float_precision = 5 ;double_precision = 15
```

Inspite of these changes, I get the result stored as only 6 decimal places both in timestamp and value. What could be a better strategy to store/see as per my expectation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sampling value: since you set it up as timestamp, cassandra will store it with milisecond precision. One way would be to store it as decimal.

The same applies to value1. Recreate your table with decimal instead of double for value1.

Comment: But I have a strict requirement to show the sampling rates column value as like these "1970-01-01 00:00:02.48979187011719+0000". Would it be possible to use a user-defined type as <timestamp, decimal>. For example, <1970-01-01 00:00:02,0.48979187011719>

However, my concern is:
i) I would like to have this udt column as primary key 
ii)  user should be able to filter queries based on timestamp or decimal part of udt

I read that cassandra's udt types suffer from both the problems. Correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: You can create your table like this

`CREATE TABLE test.temp (
    myts timestamp,
    sampling decimal,
    value1 decimal,
    PRIMARY KEY (myts, sampling)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (sampling ASC)`